# ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'Paysand'

Tags: mysql, excel, unicode, mysql-workbench, utf8mb4

I was trying to import csv data file using command prompt in MySQL Workbench (mysql  Ver 8.0.30 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)).

Using following steps:

mysql>
load data local infile 'F:/Data Analysis/Data-Analysis-Project/Global_SuperShop_Project/Global_Store.csv'

```
-> into table global_store
-> fields terminated by ','
-> enclosed by '"'
-> lines terminated by '\n'
-> ignore 1 rows;
```

ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'Paysand'

P.S: I can get rid of this error if i manually replace the value of "Paysandú" with "Paysandu" but then it shows other similar errors in that table column.

How can I convert utf8mb4 to utf-8 so mysql workbench can import the data or is there any way I can convert this in Ms-Excel??

Comment: Read and follow [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) as well as 
[UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/).

Comment: See "truncation" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution to this problem of mine. Actually, my CSV file was encoded in ANSI not in a UTF-8 format so I need to convert it first.

To convert your ANSI encoded CSV file to UTF-8 you have to open your CSV file in notepad and then click the save as option. In the popped-up window, you can see the encoding type option beside the save button. Change it to your desired format and save it.

Comment: In other words, Notepad messed up the data.

Comment: that works for small  pieces of data, but it'd be challenging to do for large data sets

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the character set of the file you are loading, unless it has the "default" character set of your MySQL server:

```
mysql> load data 
  local infile 'F:/Data Analysis/Data-Analysis-Project/Global_SuperShop_Project/Global_Store.csv'
  into table global_store
  character set latin1
  . . .
```

But you need to know what character set your file is in, of course. If `latin1` does not work, try other sets, check the full list at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I've managed to fix it by setting the raise_on_warnings to False in mysql connection configuration.

```
enter code here

def mysql_connection():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='root',      
        password='xxxxxxxxxx',
        host='127.0.0.1',
        database='xxxxxxxxxx',
        raise_on_warnings=False)
    return connection
```

Comment: This is not a solution... it's like closing your eyes not to see